# How to view github repository code with vs code interface?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, repo, code-view

when finding a suitable code in a GitHub repository we need to see what is folder structure is and also need to navigate all of the code easily to review that code. In this kind of situation, GitHub web navigation is very annoying. Because we can see one file at a time. Is there any easy way to investigate the GitHub repository easily?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very **cool feature** to do that. When we find suitable code for our projects we can investigate the GitHub repository using vs code interface,

- *It is the exact VS Code interface and that features.*
- *It is open with the browser tab.*
- *No need to clone or download that repository.*

For this you need just `go to a repo and press the '.' (full-stop) button`. **Now that repo open with vs code interface in a browser tab**.